# Complex group by query

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to make a "complex" group by query in ElasticSearch. My records has the follow format:

```
id value
0  nil
1  nil
2  nil
3 4
4 0
5 7
6 nil
7 nil
8 nil
9 nil
10 8
11 90
12 90
13 nil
14 nil
.
.
.
```

I need to group by neighboor different of nil. How can I get that?. In my example the output will be

```
id value
3 4   
4 0
5 7

id value
10 8
11 90
12 90
```

Comment: come on this is not grouping or aggregation be it SQL database.

Comment: Hi , my answer made any sense ?

Answer (score 0):

might be u r looking for this :-

```
 {
    "aggregations": {
        "agg1": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "id"
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "agg2": {
                    "filter": {
                        "not": {
                            "term": {
                                "value": "nil"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```